# Is there a closed-form solution for tangent circle in lens of two other circles?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

I am given real values $p, s, t, u$  and wish to find unknown values $r, v$.  As shown in the diagram below, $p$ and $s$ are radii of two given circles, with centers at $(0,-p)$ and $(0,t)$.

At present I'm using Newton's method to solve $a(v)=b(v)$ for $v$, with $a(v) = p - \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$ [from $(p-a)^2=u^2 + v^2$] and  $b(v) = s - \sqrt{u^2 + (t-v)^2}$ [from $(s-a)^2=u^2 + (t-v)^2$], with $a$ and $b$ representing the after-intersecting portions of rays from $(0,-p)$ and $(0,t)$.  When  $a(v)=b(v)$, we have $a(v)=b(v)=r$.  Given $r$ or $v$ it's trivial to find the other and to find tangency point G, etc.

Is there a better method, preferably some closed form, for finding $r$ or $v$ when given  $p, s, t, u$?
[image: three circles, one with unknown radius r in lens of other two]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute the distance from the centers of the two large circles to the center of the small circle in two ways: by the distance formula, and by taking the difference of their radii. This gives us the equations

\begin{align}
    (s - r)^2 &= u^2 + (v-t)^2 \\
    (p-r)^2 &= u^2 + (v+p)^2
\end{align}

These are quadratic in $r$ and $v$, but taking the difference of these two equations and simplifying gives us a linear equation in $r$ and $v$:
$$
    s^2 + (2p - 2s) r  = t^2 - (2p + 2t)v.
$$
We can solve for either unknown variable in terms of the other; for example, we can take
$$
   r = \frac{t^2 - s^2 - (2p+2t)v}{2p-2s}.
$$
Now substitute this expression for $r$ into either of the original equations, and you get a quadratic equation for $v$. This can be solved using the quadratic formula; the expression you get is messy, but still gives a closed form for $v$ (and therefore for $r$).

Answer (score 2):

The locus of the centers of the circles tangent to the two fixed circles is a hyperbola (that degenerates to a double line when $p=s$) with center at $C=\left(0,(t-p)/2\right)$ and asymptotes perpendicular to the common external tangent lines to the fixed circles. The vertices of this hyperbola are the centers of the two tangent circles that lie on the $y$-axis. We want the branch with vertex $V=\left(0,(t-s)/2\right)$. Once we have the equation of this hyperbola, finding $v$ is a matter of setting $x=u$ in the equation and solving the resulting quadratic. The radius $r$ of the tangent circle is then easily found from the radius of one of the fixed circles and the distance between its center and the resulting point.

[image]

A way to find the equation of this hyperbola is to compute the common external tangent lines to the fixed circles. Using similar triangles, these tangents intersect on the $y$-axis at a $y_0$ such that $${y_0-t\over s}={y_0+p\over p},$$ from which $$y_0 = {p(s+t)\over p-s}. \tag1$$ (We’ll assume that $p\ne s$ for now.) Omitting the gory details of the computation, the resulting tangent lines are $$(2p-s+t)x \pm (p-s)\sqrt{{2p-s+t\over s+t}}y \mp p\sqrt{(2p-s+t)(s+t)} \tag2$$ and so the equation of the hyperbola is $$\left((p-s)\sqrt{{2p-s+t\over s+t}} x\right)^2 - \left((2p-s+t)\left(y-\frac12(t-p)\right)\right)^2=k \tag3$$ for some yet-to-be-determined constant $k$. The left-hand side of (3) is just the product of the equations of the perpendiculars through $C$ to the two lines from (2). To find the correct value of $k$, substitute the coordinates of the vertex $V$ into (3), producing after simplification $k=-(p-s)^2(2p-s+t)^2/4$. When $s=p$, the equation of the hyperbola reduces to $y=(t-p)/2$, a horizontal line through $C$, which is now the midpoint of the two fixed circle centers, as one would want.

I’ll leave working out a closed-form solution for $v$ from this to you. I would avoid expanding (3) since the square for $y$ is already completed, which brings you pretty close to the solution already.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the "locus of centers of circles tangent to two fixed circles is a hyperbola" notion.  It seems to lead to an elegant approach. ~ So far, my closed-form solution code (from algebra in Maxima) isn't giving correct answers, presumably due to code errors on my part, hence not improving the clarity or robustness of the code, relative to the Newton-method code, which gives correct answers.   Will keep trying.